# Seperating an Activity's Views and it's logic

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm refactoring an activity that had grown too large. Ideally what I am trying to accomplish is to have my activity initialize all my view and set Listeners. Than off load the logic to a helper class. I pretty sure I would like to do this with an interface. But that's were I'm stuck.

For example, let have classes Main and MainHelper. Main has a CardView and a button. The button will show the cardview.

- MainHelper is what has the interface and Main implements it?
- How do I update views from MainHelper?
- Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to accomplish?

  ```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainHelper.MainActivityHelper {

   private lateinit var btn: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn)
   private lateinit var menu: CardView = findViewById(R.id.menu)

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

       btn.setOnClickListener { v: View? -> handleBtn()}

   }

   override fun handleBtn() {}
  ```

  }

  ```
  class MainHelper: AppCompatActivity() {

      interface MainActivityHelper {

         fun handleBtnM() {
              menu.visibility = View.VISIBLE

         }

  }
  ```

Comment: One best way to separate a view from it's activity or fragment is to use BindingAdapters. Using a interface is not a good choice here because you are not trying to create an abstraction.

Comment: You mean you want your Activity to set all the listeners, but the actual implementation of what is done in each listener is in your helper class? This is going to get messy fast because then your Helper class needs references to all the views it will work with in the "logic" as well as the ViewModel. So then your Activity is dependent on your helper and your helper is dependent on your Activity. It's a two-way dependency with many connections involved. Unmanageable spaghetti.

Comment: Having a lot of code in a single class doesn't necessarily mean it's unmanageable or needs to be split up. If all the things it's referencing have to be connected to each other, it may be cleanest to keep them together. If there's a group of views that don't interact with other views, you might consider creating a ViewGroup class for them so those interactions are isolated.

Comment: `MainHelper: AppCompatActivity` this definitely isn't what you're looking to do and the approach you're taking isn't going to work like this, without sounding rude, but you should focus on learning some more android basics before attempting to worry about how good your code is, once you learn what's possible and what isn't, it becomes easier to improve what you have

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this Helper class, I would recommend that you use a more modern and better tested architecture pattern like Model-View-ModelView (MVVM).  If so, you can leverage Android Jetpack's Architecture Component to help you better organize and separate concerns as explained here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide.

Here's a more in-depth explanation of Android's `ViewModel` implementation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.